# How to place input field on top of image

Tags: html, css, forms

I have certain field as a table data which i converted from psd to html.

The image is shown below ..

[image]

Part  of html code is  ...

```
<tr>
        <td colspan="13">
            <img src="images/WebDesign_32.png" width="1200" height="24" alt="" class="texxt"></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="24" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
```

How to get text from top of this `src="images/WebDesign_32.png"`  text using a form.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve but what you have is an image. So if you try to get a form that looks like this image you'd have to program this form in HTML. Otherwise it's like looking at an image of a car and asking how to to make it faster.

Comment: @Torf I want to accept name from top of  image web_design32.png by placing a form field on top of that.

Comment: how to place this input  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"> on top of image /WebDesign_32.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```css
.form-wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  display:block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.form-wrapper .form-field {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.form-wrapper .form-field label {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  min-width: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.form-wrapper .form-field input, 
.form-wrapper .form-field email, 
.form-wrapper .form-field textarea {
  width: 200px;
  background: #c9cdd7;
  border: none;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  resize: none;
}

.form-wrapper .form-field .submit-btn {
  width:100px;
  float:right;
  background: #1949cb;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-wrapper">
  <form>
    <div class="form-field">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </div>
     <div class="form-field">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" />
    </div>
     <div class="form-field">
      <label for="telephone">Telephone</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </div>
     <div class="form-field">
      <label for="message">Message</label>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-field">
      <input type="submit" class="submit-btn">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: .I already have an image as form which i created using psd. I exported it to html. I want to place an input field on top of image webDesign_32.png .Please help me do that.

Comment: try this. I added a input field on top of email field. https://jsfiddle.net/sahanHaz/shpLotaz/71/

Comment: Still not sure about that. You have an Image. It does not matter if you export it as HTML. It's still an image and has no functionality. What SahanSira did was creating an HTML-Form from that image. Now it works of course, because it's not an image any more.